# Controlling Terracotta logging level for server and clients

Tags: java, logging, terracotta, log4j

I have been searching for the right way to control terracotta logging level for both the server and clients, I found [this page](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/8564.page), but its useless.

I found a way to define the logs, data, and statistics folder paths, but not sure how to set the logging level to debug. And this is how it's done:

Inside the server tag, add:

- Path to logs folder
- path to statistics folder
  I can find any useful resources, opened like the first 30 hits on google, but still not luck.

Comment: Can you add the Terracotta version? And also clarify what you mean by the `statistics folder`

Comment: Terracotta version is 3.7.7, and there are three logging files generated by the Terracotta servers, Logs, Data, Statistics.